# Подтверждения формы паролем в отдельном окне

Tags: php, веб-программирование, yii2

Нужно сделать на yii2 подтверждения сохранения настроек через ввод пароля, с чем у меня трудностей не возникает, но мне нужно это сделать так чтоб при нажатии кнопки сохранить всплывало модельное окно с полем для ввода и только при вводе правильного пароля форма сохранялась.
Как такая штука делается, может на просторах интернета подобное видел, я что-то не нашел, кто что подскажет?
Спасибо.

**(Код писать не нужно, нужно объяснить принцип такого механизма)**

Answer (score 1):

На кнопку "сохранить" вешаете js обработчик, который вызывает модальное окно (если вы используете bootstrap то это "$('#id_modal').modal()") c импутом пароля, при нажатии сохранить, валидируете пароль и отправляете форму дальше в контроллер($('#id_form').submit())